# What does "DUNKIN DOUGH" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, american-english, jokes

### DUNKIN DOUGH

It was in a comic book typed in capital and in the book there was a part talking about riddles in English (American English).

There was a plump man having a large sum of money and this was written on piece of paper pasted on the wall in the picture. It was meant to teach the reader the meaning of the words "Dough" and "Nut" through the compound word Doughnut.

> The riddle was: "Who is a doughnut?"
>
> And the answer was: "A man crazy for money."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*DUNKIN DOUGH* is an allusion to the global chain of doughnuts-and-coffee shops [Dunkin' Donuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunkin%27_Donuts).

The joke arises because *dough* is an old US colloquialism for *money* and a *nut* is a crazy person, or one who is madly fond of something.